# asp.net MVC with Microsoft OCR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ocr

I have been trying OCR code from: [WorkOCR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts/javascript-print-text)
It works, the output is like:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF09v.jpg)

But when I change the URL to: [localhost url](http://localhost:52602/images/UploadedFiles/20180714162649141.jpg)
There is an error, and cannot work. The error message is image URL is not accessible.
output: [outputFail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy6Fn.jpg)

We also tried not to use our local URL and went online to search for an image, copy and paste the image URL, still cannot work. The error message is image URL is not accessible.
url like:[urlOnline](https://teachingresources.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Word-Family-Pic-Cover.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to run it with a debugger ?

Comment: It showing "HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
(XHR)POST - https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation=true"

Comment: I have opened the console and view the error. But the error is showing  --HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
(XHR)POST - https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation=true